# Entity Framework context and model inheritance when scaffolding in database first approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on a web application using asp.net core with entity framework with the database first approach, and I am running into some problems with scaffolding. I would like to be able to update my context and my models whenever I make a change to the database, and it seems like using the `Scaffold-DbContext` command is the way to do it. However, when running this command, I run into the problem that any extra code I've written into my models is going to be overwritten.

I have tried to solve this problem by scaffolding my models from the database into a folder called DbModels, and keeping all of the models I am currently using in my code in Models. I then made every class in Models inherit from its corresponding class in DbModels, so that I can update the models in DbModels using `Scaffold-DbContext` and keep any other code I want in Models. But the problem I run into with this is that I cannot do something like `DerivedModel d = DbContext.BaseModel.First();` because base objects cannot be assigned to derived objects.

I feel as if inheritance has to be integral to the solution to this problem, however I have been unable to make it work.

Comment: You can use partial classes for your models so you're not modifying the model classes that are automatically generated.  So, for example, if MyModel.cs is auto-generated, you can created a new class called MyModel.partial.cs

Comment: Thank you @devlincarnate, this was quite helpful. I am relatively inexperienced in C# and had never used partial classes before, but now I am more learned!

Comment: @devlincarnate can you expand on this answer? what do we set in the DbContext and OnModelCreating? when i tried making the partial class i get "Every concrete entity type in the hierarchy must have a unique discriminator value"

Comment: @microsoftvamp - no changes are needed to DbContext or OnModelCreating just for partial classes. It sounds like you have something else going on. I recommend you research the error. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68130951/how-to-extend-entities-for-dbcontext-in-separate-assembly) is a start.

Answer (score 0):

Partial class is your friend here. **Just make sure the partial view has the same name as the auto-generated class and everything should be fine.**

```
public partial class TableName 
{
    public string PropertyName {get; set;} 
 }
```

Comment: is there anything else we need to do in DbContext / onModelCreating?