# How to Extend Entities for DbContext in separate assembly

Tags: c#, .net-core, architecture, entity-framework-core, customization

In my usecase we have a baseline product which is architectured with the Clean Architecture principals in mind. So the project structure looks like this:

```
Src
|- Domain
|- Appllication
|- Persistence
|- Api
|- ...
```

We use EF Core for the persistence layer, which has DbSets per Entity `public DbSet<Customer> Customers {get;}`
Of course we have an interface for all of them.

While the base product works really well, there is now a customer who needs customization which will not be implemented in the base product. I suspect there will be more customers who need individualization in the future.

I tried to simply add Projects per customer and overwrite the existing classes / add new ones.

```
Src
|- Domain
|- Appllication
|- ...
|- Customer1
  |- Domain
  |- Application
  |- ...
```

The problem is, while I can extend the `Customer` class (let's call it `CustomerExt` from now on), the DbSet interface of course still requires the `Customer` class.
I can overwrite this with the `new` keyword but then EF complains, that it needs a discriminator column.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The discriminator value for 'CustomerExt' is 'Customer' which is the same for 'Customer'. Every concrete entity type in the hierarchy must have a unique discriminator value.
```

Now I question my whole aproach of using Customer-Specific Projects and extending the others.
While I could "decorate" the `Customer` class and simply add a FK to it, I still think this is not the right approach.

---

- Is there any guideline I can follow for scenarios like this?
- Is having different branches in git a better approach? (`master`, `customer1/master`, etc) I think this can lead to stale branches very fast if we don't merge them regularly with `master`.

Comment: I've seen products succumb, even companies go bankrupt, under the intricacies of branching code bases. For one, it's hardly testable, because the number of test cases grows exponentially. Moreover, EF is totally rigid when it comes to database structure. Try not to spoil your customers by giving them everything they ask for. Always try to find the common denominator. In the end it's in their own interest that you keep a maintainable product.

Comment: In software there are no exceptions, only rules. IMHO leave `Customer` alone. You already have code everywhere for dealing with customers that you don't want to change. You could add a 1-1 foreign key to some `CustomerExt` type for additional fields, but even then migrations are going to be a pain.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do this (supporting "customizations"), you need to put in changes that will support it on an industrial scale.

At least two vendors I have worked with do this using feature switches - any customization that they choose to take on becomes a feature on the one code base... so there are no customizations, only extensions to the sole product.

As a company, you'll need to figure out what the bar for this is (guidance on what changes will typically be accepted and why, and what won't).  You'll also want to develop some patterns so that you can more easily make similar changes in the future.

You'll want to review your architecture and see what sorts of changes you can support now, and what sorts of changes you need to support later - and if that means any re-architecture.

Most of the settings are then available to all customers as a feature/config setting, but a few are hidden and only used for "special" customers by exception...  using the same approach but juts not visible to "regular" customers.

Remember that it's not just  changes to the code and DB, but also to documentation, training materials, unit tests, even marketing, not to forget operational support, upgrades, etc.